# UIView Expand to Content inside

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that returns a `UIView`. I want to dynamically change the size of my `UIView`(fullView) based on how much text is shown in the `UITextView` (thirdTextView). I currently have my height set at 200. How can I achieve a 'dynamic height'?

**EDIT:** Updated code so far. Is only working when a subView is added to the View. I don't want this...

```
func returnView(text1: String, text2: String) -> UIView {

    let fullView = UIView()

    fullView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.83, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)
    fullView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let firstButton = UIButton()
    firstButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let secondButton = UIButton()
    secondButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let thirdTextView = UITextView()
    thirdTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    thirdTextView.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
    thirdTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
    thirdTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

    firstButton.setTitle("Button1", for: .normal)
    firstButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    firstButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    firstButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left

    secondButton.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
    secondButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    secondButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    secondButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right

    let descriptionBarStackView =  UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [firstButton, UIView() ,secondButton])
    descriptionBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    descriptionBarStackView.axis = .horizontal
    descriptionBarStackView.alignment = .fill

    let viewWithStackViews = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [descriptionBarStackView, thirdTextView])
    viewWithStackViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewWithStackViews.axis = .vertical
    viewWithStackViews.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 10, bottom: 10, right:10)
    viewWithStackViews.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    fullView.addSubview(viewWithStackViews)

//        view.addSubview(fullView)

    fullView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    fullView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    fullView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.topAnchor).isActive = true
    fullView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    fullView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    fullView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    fullView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    fullView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    return fullView
}
```

Comment: put it in stack view or calculate text height and set

Comment: @Lu_ If I put it in a stackView how do I set it to not have the set height in the fullView.frame(CGRect)?

Comment: don't, you wanted it dynamic in the end

Comment: @Lu_ If it's in a stackView you're saying it will automatically find height? What needs to be in a stackView?

Answer (score 0):

- Give delegate of textview to the class
- on textViewDidChange delegate method of textview, give height

In your scenario,

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    thirdTextView.contentSize.height = textView.contentSize.height

}
```

Comment: Hi, That isn't working for me. I need to return multiple UIView's on call. I updated my function above with what's working. It's only working if I add a subView though(I think because of the last 3 constraints). Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width anchor, and it will dynamically expand to content size for height.

```
thirdTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: Hi Jake, the problem I am having is that I need the width anchor to be equal to view.width as shown above(as it changes). I am getting an error though if I don't add it to a subview. How can I workaround this?

Comment: Ok, so there's a few things here. It looks like you're adding it to a stackView and then you're constraining the "fullView" to the stackView. However, the stackView seems to be a child of the fullView, so it should be the other way around.The stackView's constraints are not defined.
Additionally, if you want to constrain the textView to self.view - you need to have it be a direct subview of self.view:   self.view.addSubview(thirdTextView)
Then set the width anchor with the code above but the constraint replaced with: 
  (equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor)